# How to draw a vertical line without using Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, line

I am using python 3 and trying to draw a vertical line in `tkinter` but I can't find any way to draw without using `Canvas`. I googled but found nothing.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry('200x346+200+100')
mainloop()
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What about using a `Frame` with a black background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using python 3 and trying to draw a vertical line in tkinter but I can't find any way to draw without using Canvas.

No, there is no general purpose way to draw in tkinter except with the canvas.

If all you need is a vertical line to be used as a separator, you can use a frame that is one pixel wide. Or, use the `ttk.Separator` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a right triangle whose non-diagonal lines drawn with `Frame`s:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ratio = 16
    vertical_edge_len = 5
    horizontal_edge_len = 12
    hypotenuse = tk.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)
    hypotenuse.create_line(0, 0, ratio * horizontal_edge_len,
                                    ratio * vertical_edge_len, fill='green')
    vertical = tk.Frame(root, bg='red', height=ratio * vertical_edge_len,
                                                                    width=1)
    horizontal = tk.Frame(root, bg='blue', height=1,
                                            width=ratio * horizontal_edge_len)
    vertical.place(x=0, y=0)
    horizontal.place(x=0, y=ratio * vertical_edge_len)
    hypotenuse.place(x=0, y=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are using `Canvas`:`hypotenuse = tk.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)`

Comment: @RobertJames Yes, but that is a _diagonal_ line. You can remove every line that starts with `hypotenuse` and would still have vertical and horizontal lines that are drawn _without_ a `Canvas`.